# SAPUI5 Segmented Button Selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I have two Segmented button Item as Delivery and Collection in my application, I want to differentiate two button by passing Delivery as "D" flag and Collection as "C" flag from the front end, to know which button is clicked(the two buttons contains a set of fields to enter data). As I'm new to Custom SAUI5 application I Didnt know how to pass this as seperate. Experts Please Help me in it.
Below is my code,

```
 <SegmentedButton selectedKey="small" id="idSegment">
   <items>
     <SegmentedButtonItem id="idSegDel" text="Delivery" key="delKey" press="handleDelivery" />
     <SegmentedButtonItem id="idSegColl" text="Collection" key="colKey" press="handleCollection" enabled="true" />
   </items>
 </SegmentedButton>

handleCollection: function() {
    this.byId("idPanelDimension").setVisible(true);
    this.byId("idPanelDimension1").setVisible(true);
},

handleDelivery: function() {
    this.byId("idPanelDimension").setVisible(false);
    this.byId("idPanelDimension1").setVisible(false);
    this.byId("idWeight").setValue("");
    this.byId("idLength").setValue("");
    this.byId("idBreadth").setValue("");
    this.byId("idHeight").setValue("");
},
  OnCreate : function(){
   var oflagSeg = "D";  //this is only for D Flag but i need to set for both as if Delivery D is clicked or Collection C cliked.
   var oEntry = {Flag: oflagSeg,}   //Passing odata attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use press event individually for each button, as it is a aggregated control of Segmented Button. Use "Select" event in Segmented Button control and get the key of selected button. Please go through the below link where i have written code.

http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/snippix/snippets/34075

Comment: you can also set the selected button default on loading view using selectedKey property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your idea i had done it and works perfectly, below is my code.

```
var oflagSeg = "";
    var mainseg = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idRetDel1--idSegment").getSelectedKey();
    if(mainseg == "keyDel"){
        oflagSeg = "D";
    }else if(mainseg == "keyCol"){
        oflagSeg = "C";

    }
```